# What is the gamma term in the modified Bessel function of second kind of Order Zero?

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

In my version of Schaums mathematical handbook (4th edition page 156), it gives the following for $K_0$

$$
K_0= -\big(ln(x/2)+\gamma\Big) I_0(x)+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{2^2\cdot4^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{x^6}{2^2\cdot4^2\cdot6^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)+...
$$

But it doesn't define what $\gamma$ is.

Is $\gamma$ some arbitrary constant?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this could have [easily been looked up in previous sections](https://books.google.com/books?id=oHuddtlCu-AC&pg=PA3) of the book mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).